# Using .htaccess file on a PHP Cartridge

Tags: php, git, apache, .htaccess, openshift

I have successfully upload my website to the OpenShift servers using Git.

I am using PHP and MySQL cartridges. In the root directory of the website. I have the .htaccess file with the cache settings as below

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 1 month"

  # CSS
    ExpiresByType text/css                              "access plus 1 week"

  # JavaScript
    ExpiresByType application/javascript                "access plus 1 week"
</IfModule>
```

But it don't seem to work, nothing is cached. I checked the network panels in Chrome dev tools as well as the response headers doesn't indicating that it is cached.

How do I make .htaccess file work?

Comment: Maybe mod_expires isn't activated.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I found the answer, I just had to "rhc deploy" the app and that put .htaccess to work. :)